# Interactive join in r based on different variables

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two data frames as follows:

```
 df<-data.frame(
  id=c("1-1","2-2","3-3","4-4","5-5","6-6"),
  identifer=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  key=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
  product=c("productA","productB","productC","productD","productE","productF"),
  ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientD","ingredientE","ingredientF"),
  DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","System","Capsule","Capsule"))

  df_2<-data.frame(
  identifer=c(1,2,2,3,4,6),
  key=c("A","B","B","C","D","F"),
  product=c("productA","productB","productB","productCC","productDD","productFF"),
  ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientBB","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientDD","ingredeintFF"),
  DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Powder","Suspension","injection","tablet"),
  Route=c("ORAL","INHALATION","INHALATION","topical","injecatable","oral")
)
```

I want to join these two datasets first on the following variables + create a new column called "match" that describes the join:

```
1) identifier,key, product, ingredient,DF
match="identifier,key, product, ingredient,DF"
```

Then, I want to join the REMAINING rows on these variables:

```
2)identifier, key, product, DF
match="identifier,key, product,DF"
```

Then the remaining rows from step 2 on these variables, so and so forth.

```
3) identifier, key, Ingredient, DF
4) identifier, key, DF 
5) identifer, key, product, ingredient
7) identifer, key, product
8) identifer, key, ingredient 
9) identifier, key
```

And I want to return the rows that do not have a match as well. I know how to do this stepwise but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

this is the expected output:

```
df_out<-data.frame(
  identifer=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  key=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
  product_1=c("productA","productB","productC","productD","productE","productF"),
  ingredient_1=c("ingredientA","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientD","ingredientE","ingredientF"),
  DF_1=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","System","Capsule","Capsule"),
  product_2=c("productA","productB","productCC","productDD",NA,"productFF"),
  ingredient_2=c("ingredientA","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientDD",NA,"ingredeintFF"),
  DF_2=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","injection",NA,"tablet"),
  Route_2=c("ORAL","INHALATION",'topical',"injecatable",NA,"oral"),
  Match=c("identifer+key+product+ingredient+DF","identifier+key+product+ingredient+DF","identifier+key+ingredient+DF","identifer+key","None","identifer+key+product+ingredient"))
```

Comment: Hi Mel, can you please provide your expected output?

Comment: Hi @IanCampbell, added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df_2)

keyord <- list(
    c("product", "ingredient", "DF"),
    c("product", "DF"),
    c("ingredient", "DF"),
    "DF",
    c("product", "ingredient"),
    "product",
    "ingredient",
    c()
)

cols <- c("product", "ingredient", "DF", "Route")
df[, Match := NA_character_]

for (v in keyord) {
    k <- c("identifier", "key", v)
    df[df_2, on=k, c(paste0(cols, "_2"), "check") := c(mget(paste0("i.", cols)), .(TRUE))]
    df[is.na(Match) & check, Match := toString(k)]
}
setnames(df, cols, paste0(cols, "_1"), skip_absent=TRUE)
```

output:

```
    id identifier key product_1 ingredient_1       DF_1                                    Match product_2 ingredient_2       DF_2     Route_2 check
1: 1-1          1   A  productA  ingredientA     Tablet identifier, key, product, ingredient, DF  productA  ingredientA     Tablet        ORAL  TRUE
2: 2-2          2   B  productB  ingredientB     Powder identifier, key, product, ingredient, DF  productB  ingredientB     Powder  INHALATION  TRUE
3: 3-3          3   C  productC  ingredientC Suspension          identifier, key, ingredient, DF productCC  ingredientC Suspension     topical  TRUE
4: 4-4          4   D  productD  ingredientD     System                          identifier, key productDD ingredientDD  injection injecatable  TRUE
5: 5-5          5   E  productE  ingredientE    Capsule                                     <NA>      <NA>         <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    NA
6: 6-6          6   F  productF  ingredientF    Capsule     identifier, key, product, ingredient  productF  ingredientF     tablet        oral  TRUE
```

data after fixing some typos in OP:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id=c("1-1","2-2","3-3","4-4","5-5","6-6"),
    identifier=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    key=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
    product=c("productA","productB","productC","productD","productE","productF"),
    ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientD","ingredientE","ingredientF"),
    DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Suspension","System","Capsule","Capsule"))

df_2 <- data.frame(
    identifier=c(1,2,2,3,4,6),
    key=c("A","B","B","C","D","F"),
    product=c("productA","productB","productB","productCC","productDD","productF"),
    ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientBB","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientDD","ingredientF"),
    DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Powder","Suspension","injection","tablet"),
    Route=c("ORAL","INHALATION","INHALATION","topical","injecatable","oral")
)
```

---

edit for multiple matches:

```
df_2 <- data.frame( identifier=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,6), key=c("A","B","B","C","D","D","F"), product=c("productA","productB","productB","productCC","productDD","productDd","productF"), ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientBB","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientDD",NA,"ingredientF"), DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Powder","Suspension","injection",NA,"tablet"), Route=c("ORAL","INHALATION","INHALATION","topical","injecatable",NA,"oral") )
setDT(df_2)
df[, c("Match", "check") := .(NA_character_, FALSE)]

ocols <- unique(unlist(keyord))
rbindlist(lapply(keyord, function(v) {
    k <- c("identifier", "key", v)
    a <- df_2[df[(!check)], on=k, nomatch=0L, c(.(id=id),
        setNames(mget(paste0("i.", ocols)), paste0(ocols, "_1")), 
        setNames(mget(paste0("x.", c(ocols, "Route"))), paste0(c(ocols, "Route"), "_2"))) 
    ]
    df[id %chin% a$id, check := TRUE]
    a
}), use.names=TRUE)
```

output:

```
    id product_1 ingredient_1       DF_1 product_2 ingredient_2       DF_2     Route_2
1: 1-1  productA  ingredientA     Tablet  productA  ingredientA     Tablet        ORAL
2: 2-2  productB  ingredientB     Powder  productB  ingredientB     Powder  INHALATION
3: 3-3  productC  ingredientC Suspension productCC  ingredientC Suspension     topical
4: 6-6  productF  ingredientF    Capsule  productF  ingredientF     tablet        oral
5: 4-4  productD  ingredientD     System productDD ingredientDD  injection injecatable
6: 4-4  productD  ingredientD     System productDd         <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: thank you for this but this takes the first match from df_2, and df_2 may have multiple matches

Comment: Can you share a sample example and your expected output for such cases

Comment: I can't edit the question but df_2 can be like this : df_2 <- data.frame(
    identifier=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,6),
    key=c("A","B","B","C","D","D","F"),
    product=c("productA","productB","productB","productCC","productDD","productDd","productF"),
    ingredient=c("ingredientA","ingredientBB","ingredientB","ingredientC","ingredientDD",NA,"ingredientF"),
    DF=c("Tablet","Powder","Powder","Suspension","injection",NA,"tablet"),
    Route=c("ORAL","INHALATION","INHALATION","topical","injecatable",NA,"oral")
)

Comment: so identifier 4, and key=D can have two matches, and your code ( very helpful btw+ thank you) cuts it into one.

Comment: what is the desired output for this case then? There are multiple matches with the previous key groupings as well

Comment: if the highest match, for example for identifier 4-4, the highest match is identifier+key. And there could be more than 1 row that matches on identifier+key for the highest match for that row. So, I want to be able to take all the rows that match on the highest match, not just one row. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Mel i added a version to address that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might feel slightly over-engineered but achieves the expected outcome:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

get_match=function(data, cols, keys){
  rtn = ifelse(rowSums(is.na(data[paste0(cols, "_1")]))==rowSums(is.na(data[paste0(cols, "_2")])), paste(keys, collapse="+"), "None")

  rtn2 = cols %>% 
    map(~{
      case_when(as.character(data[[paste0(.x, "_1")]])==as.character(data[[paste0(.x, "_2")]])~.x)
    }) %>% 
    reduce(paste, sep="+") %>% str_replace_all("\\+?NA\\+?", "")

  paste(rtn, rtn2, sep="+") %>% str_replace_all("\\+$", "")
}

df_out = left_join(df, df_2, by=c("identifer", "key"), suffix=c("_1", "_2")) %>% 
    mutate(Match = get_match(., cols=c("product", "ingredient", "DF"), keys=c("identifer", "key")), 
           match_strength = str_count(Match, "\\+")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(match_strength==max(match_strength, na.rm=TRUE))
```

`dplyr::left_join` removes the `by` keys so the only way I found to add them is to check that all the `_1` or the `_2` were missing. I could have used the `keep=TRUE` option and remove/rename them hereafter though...

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for this but I updated my dataset. For a given identifier+key, I could have two matches, for example look at identifer 2, and key B. I could match on identifer+key+product+DF, and identifer+key+product+ingredient+DF. I updated the dataset to reflect that but I only want the row that has the most matches given the hierachy of the joins so the row identifer+key+product+ingredient+DF. And also running your code for my full dataset, I got None+DF which shouldn't be a combo?

Comment: Hi Mel. Your updated dataset seems incorrect to me, as there should not be any duplicate in an identifier column. Still, if `key` is not an identifier, you can remove it from `by=` and from `keys=`.

Comment: They are usually duplicates in the second dataset- that's why I needed to create a heirachy of matches. My goal is to to have one match per id for df. I added an id column as well.

Comment: @Mel then there is a piece of logic that I'm missing: what rule makes you conclude that `df_out[2,"ingredient_2"]` is `"ingredientB"` and not `"ingredientBB"`?

Comment: I have two matches on df_out[2,ingredient_2], one of the rows match on identifer+key+product+DF which means that the ingredient isn't the same (ingredient BB), and one of the rows matches on identifer+key+product+ ingredient+DF. This is the match I want to keep in my final dataset since more fields match. I want to join based on on the numbers I provided. if I get the first join, then i would remove that row, and so on so forth

Comment: @Mel OK, then you have to measure the strength of the match, and then keep only the strongest one. I edited my answer to this end. Is it better? I measured the strength by counting the `+` in `Match`, but there might be more efficient ways to do that.

Comment: That helps, but I'm wondering if there is a way to establish an order of join? first join by this criteria then the second and so on and so forth

Comment: @Mel yes, you might want to figure out some better algorithm to calculate `match_strength`, like one that handles ties, but that is up to you